# Why does it take different times to execute threads of the same behavior?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to multithreading. I have a program that consists of two classes: PrimeNumber and a main class. I'm trying to find all the prime numbers in a given range.
Here's my PrimeNumber class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class PrimeNumber extends Thread{

    int start, end;
    int threadNumber; //used to display the thread number
    static ArrayList<Integer> list  = new ArrayList<Integer>(1000000);


    public PrimeNumber(int start, int end, int threadNumber) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
          // added code
            if(list.isEmpty()){
            list.add(2);
        }


    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(threadNumber + " started");
        for(int i = start; i<=end;i++){
            if(isPrime(i)){
                list.add(i);
            }

        }
        System.out.println(threadNumber + " has finished");
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("Time for thread " + threadNumber + " is " +TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(endTime-startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) + " seconds.");

    }  

//modified method
/**
 *  Determine whether a number is prime 
 * @param number
 * @return true if number is prime, false otherwise
 */


     public boolean isPrime(int number){
        if(number == 0 || number == 1){
            return false;
        }

        else {
            int counter = 0;
            while(counter<list.size()){
                if(number%list.get(counter)==0){
                    return false;
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
  }
```

and here's my main class

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        final int maxNumberOfThreads = 3; // number of threads I want to create
        final int maxNumber = 900000;   // Max range for which I'm finding all the prime numbers up to it
        int initialNumber = 1;
        ArrayList<Thread> myList = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for(int i = 0; i < maxNumberOfThreads; i++ ){
            myList.add(new PrimeNumber(initialNumber, initialNumber+ maxNumber/maxNumberOfThreads, i+1));
            myList.get(i).start();
            initialNumber+=maxNumber/maxNumberOfThreads;
        }

        for(Thread thread : myList){

            thread.join();
        }
        try {
            Collections.sort(PrimeNumber.list); // sort the list
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("Primes.txt"),true));
            for(int i = 0; i <PrimeNumber.list.size(); i++){
                writer.write(PrimeNumber.list.get(i).toString());
                //System.out.println(PrimeNumber.list.get(i));
                writer.newLine();
            }
            writer.close();
            System.out.println("Done writing to the file");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my program here's the output I get:

```
2 started
3 started
1 started
1 has finished
Time for thread 1 is 3 seconds.
2 has finished
Time for thread 2 is 7 seconds.
3 has finished
Time for thread 3 is 11 seconds.
Done writing to the file
```

Even though the threads have similar behaviors (they all calculate the prime numbers on almost identical *ranges*) why is the execution time different for each thread?
I've searched for quite some time but didn't find a satisfying answer. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I've added a step in my `isPrime()` method which improved the execution time greatly.

Comment: Because your computer is doing other things too.

Comment: _on almost identical ranges_

Comment: I understand that. But if I increase maxNumber to 9 mill let's say, the time difference between each thread gets significantly high (20 seconds or more)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop in method isPrime performs more iterations on thread 3 than on thread 2, and more iterations on thread 2 than on thread 1, since numbers tested are different in each case:

```
     for(int i = 2; i< number; i++)
    {
        if(number%i ==0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```

Also, the number of primes in each of the three ranges is different, so the number of additions to the list will be different too.

Comment: Also check for overhead with List.Add().

Comment: @neutrino I can't believe I missed something like this. Thanks mate :)

Comment: In addition: remember that each thread has to actually run on a physical core of your CPU. If you have less than 3 cores, one just has to wait.

Comment: @TwoThe I have a four-core processor :)

Comment: Just sayin'... and then still some could be busy. ;)

Comment: @TwoThe I've optimized my isPrime() method again. The program should be much faster now. The time for each thread now is very very close (one second difference in most cases with numbers larger than 1 mill) :)